# Improve Facebook app load time

Tags: facebook, facebook-apps, page-load-time

I have a Facebook news app. It takes a bit of time to load the webpage in the app. But an app like Washington post loads the page much faster. How do I make my app load faster?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please see the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) for how to ask questions here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some things you could do are :

- [Minify](http://code.google.com/p/minify/) all JavaScript and CSS files.
- Ensure all images used are as small as possible ( talking about the size of the file )
- Consider condensing your images into a ["sprite"](http://css-tricks.com/css-sprites/) file.
- Make sure you are not making any unnecessary API calls before the page loads
- Refactor your code and review your code logic.
- Use google chrome's ["network" panel](http://code.google.com/chrome/devtools/docs/network.html) to monitor what resources are being loaded and how long they are taking.
- If you are using jQuery - consider [loading the libraries from Google's CDN](http://encosia.com/3-reasons-why-you-should-let-google-host-jquery-for-you/)

*Saying that "app like Washington post loads the page very quick..." doesn't help anyone - who knows how many developers and how much time they put into their application.   All you can do is make it the best that you can with the tools and resources that you have at your disposal...*

If you find a specific issue with your application that you see is slowing things down and you still do not know how to improve the load time - come back here and edit your question to contain more information about that specific problem.

Happy coding!